# How to send multiple attributes in multiple java files in xreq.send method

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to send an attribute to multiple locations in AJAX?

I have a scenario like this

```
xreq.open("POST","ComponentServlet?&projectName=abc",true);
xreq.open("POST","schemaservlet?&projectName=abc",true);
```

Can I send these two parameters in one `xreq.send` command?